# Reading multiple text files using 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, loops, literals

```
data = []

input_files = teams_files
for filename in teams_files:
    with open(filename) as f:
        data.append(f.read().split())
```

I get an error for the above error when trying to import multiple large files int 2D array

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: *import multiple large files int 2d array* - ?

Comment: Provide a complete and executable code snapshot (what is teams_files) and include the error in the question